# Updating Vue.Js data with secondary ajax request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some working code with Vue.js v2.5.16 that updates existing data, but I am not sure if I am following best practices.

What I am doing:

I call a properties.view() method (which I omitted below for brevity) to quickly grab basic data from a redis cache on load. I then call  properties.available() to retrieve non-cached inventory data.

Questions:

1. Is there a efficient way to update my properties objects without having to "manually" do it like via some sort of "magic" data binding? I tried the v-model directive but couldn't get it jiving.
2. When updating property.rate.low.total.nightly_avg I can only reference the first level attribute "rate" I then have to build out the object I am going to update to get all the way down to the child. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

JS Code:

```
    var properties = new Vue({
    el: '#properties',
    data: {
        properties: []
    },
    methods: {
        available: function(){
            let self = this;

            axios
                .get(searchJs.getAttribute('webroot') + 'properties/available', {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response){
                    for (let i=0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        let p = response.data[i];
                        let vData = self.properties.filter(function(property) {
                            if (property.id == p.id) {
                                return property;
                            }
                        });
                        self.$set(vData[0], 'rate', {
                            'low':{
                                'total': {
                                    'nightly_avg': p.rate.low.total.nightly_avg,
                                    'original_nightly_avg': p.rate.low.total.original_nightly_avg
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        },
    }
});
```

HTML snippet:

```
        <div class="property-card_price-book">

            <span class="strikethrough-price">${{property.rate.low.total.original_nightly_avg}}</span>

            <span class="price">${{property.rate.low.total.nightly_avg}}</span>

            <div class="offer">

                <figure>
                    <span></span>
                    <sep></sep> 
                    <span></span>
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>
```